# SVN commands failed when try to find the blame information from svn

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I've just installed SCM Activity plugin 1.8 in Sonar 4.5 following the installation procedure. So Subversion is also available on the server where Sonar is installed as well.

I want to extract the blame information from SVN and want to show in the SoanrQube i.e., whenever a new issue arises it automatically assign to the culprit.

However as soon as I start a jenkins 1.532 job to run Sonar metrics, I've got the following warning in the output console:

```
Fail to retrieve SCM info of: /export/bld/monetbld/jenkins/workspace/MONET/monet-service/src/com/monet/service/server/query/events/EventQuery.java. Reason: The svn command failed. 
[sonar:sonar] svn: '.' is not a working copy 
[sonar:sonar] mv: cannot stat `/export/bld/monetbld/.subversion/servers_TMP': No such file or directory 

[sonar:sonar] 05:49:40.002 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8 done: 26590 ms 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:40.002 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 26590 ms 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:40.014 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped)... 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:40.014 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:40.035 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:42.355 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped) done: 2341 ms 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:42.528 INFO  - Execute decorators... 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:49.291 WARN  - Unable to assign issue [03fea3ce-2d42-4d9d-bea9-9921815562e6] 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:49.291 WARN  - Unable to assign issue [61a32323-7c60-4724-adcd-0523bb3bf188] 
[sonar:sonar] 05:49:49.298 WARN  - Unable to assign issue [ef6d4a2d-2875-4ee1-8ed8-1330da9d8931]
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: ` svn: '.' is not a working copy `

Comment: @bahrep: What you want to say? i didnot get it.

Comment: He's saying to read your log, which tells you pretty explicitly at least one problem. You did not provide a working copy for your tool to do SVN things on. Your directory path has the word "export" in the name which indicates this likely is an export rather than a checkout. It appears your tool requires a checkout (working copy).

Answer (score 0):

Totally Agree with @bahrep

As per the logs provided by you, its a export of your codebase and its just taking a copy of the current state of the repository and will not have any way to commit back your changes.

Also, as its an export for your codebase which not includes `.svn` directories(which is required for SonarQube SCM plugin to generate Blame report)

Solution would be to checkout your codebase (which includes the `.svn` directories) and do the SonarQube scan.

Comment: i am using jenkins for building and when i configure jenkins for this job, i choose option "Always checkout fresh copy". that checkout directory is already there. i just install jenkins there that is why it has path name 'export'.